# How to select a category in frontend when creating an article?

Tags: category

How to enable a frontend user to select a category when creating an article?

When the user attempts to create a new article, the 'Category' drop down, under Publishing, is disabled. Is there a way to enable the dropdown so that a user can select a category?

User is in manager group and can create, edit .. etc.

[image]